# Initialize tuple with class templated on each type of variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, stdtuple

The title is probably hard to parse so here's what I mean. Let's say I have a few classes A, B1, B2, B3... Bn where I'd like to hold a tuple of A's templated on some B class. A valid final result could be something like `tuple<A<B3>, A<B1>> _chain`. This would be contained within a container class we'll call C. What I'm looking for is to initialize C with a bunch of B types that then get wrapped in my A class. I can't simply do

```
template<class... T>
class C
{
    std::tuple<T...> _chain;
public:
    C(const T&... t) : _chain(t...) { }
};
```

because then I'd end up with a tuple of Bs. Is there an ergonomic way to wrap the init step (`_chain(t...)`) so that I'll end up with a tuple of A's templated on the B classes I pass to the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
template<template <typename> typename Base, class... T>
class C
{
    std::tuple<Base<T>...> _chain;
public:
    C(const Base<T>&... t) : _chain(t...) { }
};
```

You can use it like this: `C<A, B1, B2, B3> c;`

`_chain` will then be a tuple `tuple<A<B1>, A<B2>, A<B3>>`.

Comment: Very interesting, that looks like it would work. What if this particular class C was always going to use A to template on? Would it be possible to remove the need to specify A?

Comment: @Keltek of course. Just remove `template <typename> typename Base` from the template signature and replace `Base` inside the class with `A`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and get back to you. In retrospect this was so obvious.